# How to save a map service to a local drive.. Forest Service Ranger Districts

Tags: arcgis-server, web-service, offline

I am using a map service in a project. I would like to find out if it is possible to save it to my local computer.

This is what I am looking at:

Server: http://apps.fs.fed.us/ArcX/services
Name: EDW/EDW_RangerDistricts_01
Map Service Type: Not Cached

Answer (score 1):

This is a MapService, being served by ArcGIS Server. It is not possible to `save the map to disk` because as such there is no map.

It is a service, which responds to requests.

There are some ways of getting the data out from the service, but they lie in a grey area(legally speaking), so I won't mention them in detail

Your best bet would be to contact them, and ask for the raw data.